# create a REST service using jersey?

Tags: java, http, rest, jersey

I followed [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) (paragraph 7) tutorial to create a Rest service using jersey. However in the end i was kinda disappointed as it wasn't exactly what i was looking for.

What i had in mind was to create a java server with jersey that a client could make post requests to it , and the server could save the data in a MySQL database.

In the tutorial i was shown maybe how to make a post request? And even for that i used some html and 4 different java classes without any explanation on what anything does. In php the same thing was less than 40 lines of code and everything actually made sense.

I am not sure where to go from here , as everyone suggested to me to read this tutorial for what i needed. But i can't see why as i don't understand its purpose.

Do you know any tutorial i could have a look at , or point me to the right direction here? I ve never developed in java before neither have i used tomcat , so everything seems pretty new to me. I was used to php and apache.

Comment: Seems like you just found a tutorial that doesn't suit your needs. try [this](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2011/08/15/a-simple-java-web-stack-with-guice-jetty-jersey-and-jackson/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you have mentioned focus on creating RESTful Webservices with Java. It aims at distributed systems, where a client can make requests to a server. I think the tutorial is very helpful for that matter.

On the other hand, you seem to be searching for a tutorial that helps you creating a web application that can save/retrieve data to/from a database. You can find one, for example, in http://zetcode.com/tutorials/jeetutorials/mysqldatabase/

Then, for web clients, you have different alternatives, such as GWT or JSF. Also, for the persistence layer you might want to check Hibernate or JPA.

Relatively to Tomcat, it implements the Java Servlet and the JavaServer Pages (JSP) specifications from Sun Microsystems, and provides a "pure Java" HTTP web server environment for Java code to run. In short, Tomcat is the place where you deploy and run your Java web application; like you deploy a PHP application in Apache (with PHP installed).